# Как скопировать массив в динамический массив? (Си)

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, malloc

Есть массив `char str[] = "abcdef";`

И динамический массив:
`char *dstr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * N);`

Как скопировать `str[]` в `dstr[]` ?

P.S. Заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть 3 способа, нативное копирование области памяти, специальной функцией копирования строк, посимвольный перебор массива и запись в `dstr`.

```
memcpy(&str, &dstr, strlen(str) + 1); // Копирование области памяти
```

```
strcpy(dstr, str); // Специальная функция для строки
```

```
// Перебор массива циклом.

int strsize = strlen(str) + 1;
for(int i = 0; i < strsize ; i++)
{
    dstr[i] = str[i];
}
```

Имейте ввиду, в обоих случаях вы должны быть уверены что размер `dstr` больше  на `1` чем **длина** строки `str`.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Вместо `i < strsize` лучше использовать `str[i]`, тогда и длину считать не придётся. Кстати, в случае с длиной можно было использовать `<=`, чтобы нолик сам скопировался.

Comment: Код содержит ошибки/странности! Если `strsize = strlen(str) + 1`, то тогда правильная позиция для замыкающего нуля - это `dstr[strsize - 1]`, а не `dstr[strsize]`. Вы на самом деле уже скопировали этот ноль основным циклом. `dstr[strsize] = '\0'` уже делать не надо и позиция `dstr[strsize]` для нуля - неправильная.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Нолик и так уже "сам копируется" благодаря `strsize = strlen(str) + 1`. А финальное `dstr[strsize] = '\0'` - это какая-то ненужная бессмыслица.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я бы в переборе не использовал `strlen` - по сути лишний проход по массиву. Достаточно `int i; for(i = 0; str[i]; i++) dstr[i] = str[i]; dstr[i] = 0;`

Comment: Точно, не заметил.

Comment: @AnT, да, я `+1` не заметил - тогда действительно `<`.

Comment: Сейчас уже вообще жесткие ошибки в цикле копирования пошли. Если `+1`, то почему тогда `<=`? Это уже вылет за пределы исходной строки.

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае (создание копии строки, не содержащей двоичных нулей) проще всего
(а если размер исходной строки не известен, то и не менее эффективно, чем использование `malloc` с последующими вызовами `strlen`, а затем `strcpy` или `memcpy`)
вызвать [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)

Например:

```
#include <string.h>

...

    char str[] = "abcdef";
    char *dstr = strdup(str);
```

Конечно, возвращаемый указатель стоит проверить на `NULL` (аналогично использованию `malloc`).